# Set value for another controller

Tags: ios

I have 2 view **Fistcontroller** and **Secondcontroller**

I want set a value of Secondcontroller from Fistcontroller

I had try on Secondcontroller

```
@property (nonatomic) int value;
```

in .h file

and

```
@synthesize value;
```

in .m file

In Fistcontroller, I use this code to set value but it not work !

```
Secondcontroller *secondview = [Secondcontroller alloc]init];
 secondview.value = 1;
```

That problem, when to secondcontroller value of value is 0 not 1 ???

Comment: Where in your code did you assign the value?  Why do you think it "didn't work"?

Comment: I debug and view value . I have a funtion if in secondcontroller to check value !

Comment: @MrTranDinhDuc - You need to get current instance of a viewController in which you want to set value - what you are using Storyboard or xib ??

Comment: How do you present `Secondcontroller`?

Comment: shouldn't "@synthesize" adsloaded be "@synthesize" value?

Comment: value in Secondcontroller. I set in Fistcontrller => seconview.value = 1;

Comment: Are you sure the instance of `Secondcontroller` you are presenting is the same as the one you are creating in `Secondcontroller *secondview = [Secondcontroller alloc]init];`. I'll bet it isn't.

Comment: @ElGuapo Thanks but it not work !

Comment: @mprivat I sure, because I can call them at Fistcontroller !

Comment: @MrTranDinhDuc: Show us the code when you go to `Secondcontroller` For me, it's the same issue, that why I asked about how do you present it.

Comment: After `secondview.value = 1;`, do `NSLog(@"%@", secondview);`. Inside your second view controller, in `viewWillAppear:`, do `NSLog(@"%@", self);`. If it prints the same thing twice, then I'll believe you. If it doesn't, then you'll believe us.

Comment: Thanks for everybody ! I did !